# Phalcon - Calling function from other controller

Tags: php, controller, phalcon

How to call function from another controller in Phalcon PHP framework. Here is example for CakePHP http://sherwinrobles.blogspot.com/2013/02/cakephp-calling-function-from-other.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the link you provided, to my knowledge there is no direct way to call a function in another controller using the request object. However instantiating the controller and calling the function will work just it does in CakePHP

```
$newController = new \MyNS\Controllers\NewController();
$newController->myFunc();
```

If you want you can use a static function inside the controller and call it

```
\MyNS\Controllers\NewController::myFunc();
```

Comment: Tnx Nikolaos:) i think this way should be faster than using request object

Comment: This one worked, but what if it is a $_POST request?

Answer (score 0):

This is already Tested

For the people that aren't using CakePHP 
another way to do this would be to do a helper Folder and write actions, in this case methods.

public/index.php

Add the path helper

```
$loader->registerDirs(
    [
        APP_PATH . '/helper/'
    ]
);
```

Add a helper Order in apps

```
└── apps
    ├── controllers
       └─ exampleController.php  
    ├── models
    └── helpers
       └─ myHelper.php
    ...
```

In myHelper.php

```
 <?php

    use Phalcon\Di\Injectable;

    class myHelper extends Injectable
        {
          function myNameFunction() {   
          // here you should write your function

        }
    }
```

In exampleController where you want to call the other action, in this case function

```
<?php

use Phalcon\Mvc\Controller;

class exampleController extends Controller {
  public function yourAction() {
    //your code   
    //there are 2 ways of calling the function. either use this one
    $myHelper = new myHelper();
    $myHelper->myNameFunction();

    //or this one
    (new UnmatchHelper())->myNameFunction();
  }
}
```